# Как мы соеденины в сети интернет?

Tags: сеть

Здравствуйте. Скорее всего мой вопрос глупый, но всё же я хотел бы, чтобы мне объяснили, **как соединены компьютеры во всемирной сети?**

Ну вот в моём ПК вставлен кабель, который ведёт к провайдеру. И что дальше? Куда он ведёт дальше? Если все компьютеры связаны кабелем, то каким образом связали континенты? Спутники?

Прочитав Википедию я узнал, что *первые компьютеры, создавшие "сеть"(были способом передачи информации для военных США), были связаны кабелем*, без всяких провайдеров. Зачем они тогда нужны? И как понимать термин `скорость Интернет-соединения`, от чего она зависит в тех. плане? Или всё дело в деньгах ?

Comment: Континенты тоже связаны проводами https://habrahabr.ru/post/228415/

Comment: @iksuy, да ладно... Но это как-то глупо, или нет?

Comment: @Levelleor Ну ДНС тут явно не причем. Это просто служба трансляции имен в IP адреса. Да и ссылка не совсем в кассу.

Comment: вот тут гораздо лучше рассказано https://te-st.ru/2014/06/24/15-maps-explain-internet/ А не с точки зрения именно WWW

Comment: Да, там где кабеля нет (у нас Камчатка, Чукотка ...)  связь через спутник (или радиорелейный канал)

Comment: Интернет-провайдеры - компании, которые строят сети и соединяют свои сети с другими провайдерами. Совокупность всех провайдеров и их сетей и есть интернет. Скорость - да, в общем то упирается в деньги. Строительство межконтинентальных каналов и запуск спутников стоят бешеных денег, плюс горы оборудования и электроэнергии. Для увеличения скорости разрабатываются новые технологии, но в итоге все равно все упирается в пропускную способность кабеля и приходится класть новые кабели

Comment: И наземные(подводные) каналы совсем не глупо. Информация проходит гораздо быстрее. Спутники висят на высоте ~ 35000 км. Длина экватора 40000км. Сигнал для передачи через спутник должен подняться и спуститься опять, т.е. пройти 70 тыс. км. что явно больше, чем кабель который обогнет всю землю и вернется обратно. А скорость распространения сигнала и в кабеле и в воздухе/вакууме одинакова. И в отическом кабеле помех значительно меньше, чем в воздухе.

Comment: Еще полезно, для понимания глобальной сети, почитать про [Tier 1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tier-1-операторы) операторов связи.

Comment: @Mike Справедливости ради надо отметить, что в оптоволокне скорость света все-таки будет несколько пониже, чем в вакууме.

Answer (score 6):

На самом деле все просто - если абстрагироваться от оптоволокна радиосигнала и тд все компьютеры которые подключены к интернету имеют между собой соединение - есть компьютеры один в США, другой у Вас дома и оба подключены к интернету- можно представить, что они связаны длинным кабелем(это для простоты).

Как сетевые устройства видят друг друга?! 
У каждого компьютера в сети должен быть ip адрес, при этом в сети не должно быть одинаковых адресов- иначе другие участники сети не будут знать к кому обращаться и произойдет конфликт.

Как выглядит это?! 
Ip адрес 192.168.1.1 например так(ip версии 4),- максимальное значение адресов 255.255.255.254, минимальное 0.0.0.1 - не буду вдаваться в тонкости подсчета но если посчитать все доступные ip адреса получится, что уникальных ip адресов около 16 миллионов, если не ошибаюсь.

Отсюда и проблема, что устройств( компьютеров смартфоноф планшетов и тд) в глобальной сети явно больше чем 16 миллионов.

Как же тогда это все работает?! 
Есть первые 16 миллионов компьютеров подключенные между собой в одну локальную сеть, навезем эту сеть Л1, есть еще 16 миллионов компьютеров подключенных между собой( Л2 ). Как объединить две эти сети- в сетях Л1 и Л2 должен быть хотя бы один компьютер с 2мя сетевыми картами  подключенные друг к другу, соответственно на этих сетевых картах могут быть свои ip адреса так как эти два компьютера образуют сеть Л3( хоть всего и два компьютера). И если все правильно настроенное - то есть есть маршрутизация компьютер из сети Л1 может передавать данные компьютеры в сети Л2 через сеть Л3, и получится что 32 миллиона компьютеров объедены в сеть. Но компьютеров с 2мя сетевыми картами может быть гораздо больше чем один, и каждую сеть нужно маршрутизировать и тд...

Собственно за что берет деньги провайдер - 
есть диапазон ip адресов выделенных каждой стране из первых 16 милионов, далее федеральные провайдеры масштабируют сеть более мелким провайдерам, которые масштабируют сесть пользователям, так вот так или иначе все соединенно проводом, а провайдер берет деньги по сути не за интернет а за обслуживания этих проводов, прокладку новых ремонт старых + серверное оборудование которое маршрутизирует это все хозяйство, свитчи и многое другое + расходы на электричество и зарплаты сотрудникам которые все это дело поддерживают в работоспособном состоянии.

Почему стоимость разная за скорость интернета?! 
все просто- пропускная способность кабеля ограничена физически- то есть гигабитный кабель больше этого гигабита не пропустит и все тут- пользователей много кабель одни- соответственно между пользователями этот кабель приходится делить, и кто больше заплатил тот меньше поделился с другими=)

Все вышесказанное написано очень условно, на пальцах, для школьников- но главное мне кажется принцип работы сразу становится понятным.

Comment: Прокомментирую себя=)) Вопрос прочел еще раз, в своем ответе не сказал как между собой соединены континенты, провайдеры и тд.
Континенты соединены между собой толстенными оптоволоконными кабелями по дну морей и океанов. А принцип спутниковой связи - спутник дает отлько ответы на запросы,  что бы отправить спутнику этот самый запрос нужно оборудование которое есть только у тех кто эти спутники и запускает сообственно, то есть вы должны иметь соединение с провайдером который спутником ведует, хоть по телефонной линии или другими средствами.

Comment: Лучше перенесите свой комментарий в текст ответа. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/189/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8

Comment: А перед этим зайдите в гугл и вбейте запрос "двухсторонний спутниковый интернет", я сам сейчас удивлен был, думал двухстороние комплекты оборудования гораздо дороже, сильно подешевели за последние годы. Так что ваш "спутник дает только ответы" абсолютно некорректен, оборудование для двусторонней связи запрос-ответ через спутник доступно и даже доступно по деньгам

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А я думал, что связь устроена поинтересней, чем просто связь кабелей)

Comment: @АртурКлочко на самом деле она устроена очень сложно. В глобальных сетях те принципы, которые описаны выше начинают работать слишком медленно и начинают применятся различные интересные технологии - mpls, vlan и прочее. Но в общих чертах сеть работает именно так.

Comment: @АлександрБогомяков Мг, понял, погуглю, спасибо